# Excel formula for organizing data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like a formula that could organize data by:

1. deleting or ignoring the #N/A.
2. give me the cells that have a numerical value and are in order by week number.

For example:

```
                WK25   WK26   WK28   WK31
```

Row #1 would be.....

```
                0.58   0.54   0.92   0.86
```

-

```
WK22    WK23    WK24    WK25    WK26    WK27    WK28    WK29    WK30    WK31
va  va  va  va  va  va  va  va  va  va
#N/A    #N/A    #N/A    0.58    0.54    #N/A    0.92    #N/A    #N/A    0.86
#N/A    0.56    0.56    0.56    0.56    #N/A    0.56    #N/A    #N/A    0.56
#N/A    #N/A    0.00    0.58    0.58    #N/A    0.46    #N/A    #N/A    0.56
#N/A    #N/A    #N/A    0.20    0.22    #N/A    0.21    #N/A    #N/A    0.21
```

Comment: I'm sure you'd need to write a macro for this?

Answer (score 0):

The first two are easy. Use formula isnumber by creating a table next to yours with as many columns and rows with each cell pointing to the corresponding cell in your table with contents like:

```
if(isnumber(cellref),cellref,"")
```

(3) is harder but maybe I can come up with something.

Comment: Thank You for your support.  Please let me know if you come up with anything.

Comment: I could do it using pivot tables but it requires clicking a button for each column. I assume you have a lot of those since they look like weeks. How many columns are there? If there aren't too many of either rows or columns we could transpose to put the fewest as columns.  Otherwise, oldmud0 might be right. :( But I'm also assuming you don't do macros.